# phpmyadmin user interface repeating all clickable links

Tags: laravel, nginx, phpmyadmin, digital-ocean

Pretty much all click-able links in my interface are repeated twice. I for the life of me can't understand why or how to fix it. Everything else is working fine. Help would be much appreciated! Running digitalocean ubuntu 14.04 NGINX w/ laravel 4
    https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddbHW.jpg

**side note:** on top of installation I had to edit the sites-available/default file by
inserting manually phpmyadmin location to give priority in order to bypass laravel wanting to override.

addition that was made >>

```
location ^~ /phpmyadmin {
try_files $uri =404;
root /usr/share/; 
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
fastcgi_index index.php;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
           }
```

**[SOLUTION]**

I did not have the proper code in my nginx config file so it wasn't pulling proper file extentions for pma dependencies. Able to get it running normal by adding the following code to my nginx config file.

Note* fastcgi_pass along with other variables may differ depending on your server.

```
location ^~/phpmyadmin {
           root /usr/share/;
           index index.php index.html index.htm;
           location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
                   try_files $uri =404;
                   root /usr/share/;
                   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                   fastcgi_index index.php;
                   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                   include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
           }
           location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
                   root /usr/share/;
           }
    }
    location /phpMyAdmin {
           rewrite ^/* /phpmyadmin last;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[SOLUTION]**

I did not have the proper code in my nginx config file so it wasn't pulling proper file extentions for pma dependencies. Able to get it running normal by adding the following code to my nginx config file.

**Note*** fastcgi_pass along with other variables may differ depending on your server.

```
location ^~/phpmyadmin {
       root /usr/share/;
       index index.php index.html index.htm;
       location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
               try_files $uri =404;
               root /usr/share/;
               fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
               fastcgi_index index.php;
               fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
               include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
       }
       location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
               root /usr/share/;
       }
}
location /phpMyAdmin {
       rewrite ^/* /phpmyadmin last;
}
```