# phpmyadmin UI shows double labels

Tags: phpmyadmin

phpmyadmin shows double the labels on the tabs and the left panel is not readable

I found in another post the same issue ([phpmyadmin user interface repeating all clickable links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27242486/phpmyadmin-user-interface-repeating-all-clickable-links)) but the solution did not work for me .
I have Ubuntu 16.04, php7, nginx 1.10.3 and the latest phpmyadmin.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Solved

I had to install first php-fpm and then in /etc/nginx/sites-available/default to replace "fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;" with "fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;".

The final code is

```
location ^~/phpmyadmin {
           root /usr/share/;
           index index.php index.html index.htm;
           location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
                   try_files $uri =404;
                   root /usr/share/;
                   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
                   fastcgi_index index.php;
                   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                   include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
           }
           location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
                   root /usr/share/;
           }
    }
    location /phpMyAdmin {
           rewrite ^/* /phpmyadmin last;
    }  
}
```